# Меню взаимодействия для выдачи роли

Tags: python, discord

```
class PastelColor(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @discord.ui.select(
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Модератор", value="950733445175312444", emoji="<:3446blurplecertifiedmoderator:1014627626243063849>", description="Модерация дискорд сервера"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Администратор", value="950687285312122880", emoji="<:9023blurpleemployee:1014628089961132172>", description="Модерация дискорд сервера"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Игрок", value="950722901177425950", emoji="<:German_Cross5:1078662233179037776>", description="Пользователь дискорда"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Активный", value="950723959182221312", emoji="<:3460verified:1014628088153387048>", description="Пользователь дискорда")
        ]
    )
    async def select_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
        roles = [interaction.guild.get_role(int(o.value)) for o in select.options]
        await interaction.user.add_roles(interaction.guild.get_role(int(select.values[0])))


@bot.command()
async def role(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Тестинг", view=PastelColor())
```

--ОШИБКА--

> roles = [interaction.guild.get_role(int(o.value)) for o in select.options]
> AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'options'

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблемку

Делал все что мог, ничего не получилось)